# Show value of last point as label or tooltip on Highcharts Stock Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have multiple data series with different scale in one  stock chart (HighCharts).

I want to connect each series to it's axis or show value of last point of each series on it (something like data label but just for last point of each series)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            type: 'datetime'
        }],
        yAxis: [{
            opposite: true,
          lineWidth: 1
        },{
            opposite: true,
          lineWidth: 1
        }],

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
            yAxis: 1
        }, {
            data: [20000, 2250, 30300, 28000, 27000, 27800, 25800],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
        }]

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HamedMahdizadeh/4wjc02dw/2/

HighStock
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to add a simple data formatter to have the datalables to be displayed only on the last datapoint.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function(){
                    var isLast = false;
                    if(this.point.x === this.series.data[this.series.data.length -1].x && this.point.y === this.series.data[this.series.data.length -1].y) isLast = true;

                  return isLast ? this.y : '';
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wjc02dw/4/)

Comment: Unfortunately I have a performance problem with formatter with large data. If I use a few simple condition for adding datalable to special points, it takes a long time for drawing chart so I tried to use update method of groupedData in redraw event to add datalable for special points but if I pass false to update method for disabling redraw I will face with error #15 and if I set redraw parameter of update method to true I will face another error (probably for recursive endless call of redraw method) do you have any idea for setting datalables?

Comment: how large is your data? You can try looping through your data before drawing the chart and set datalabels individually for your datapoint. Like this:[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cha9ugqu/4/) (look at the last poin of the serie)

Comment: 5-10 series with 20000 record(max).I think I should set labels on data as you told. thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should also consider a different data visualization that can better represent that much data. Or maybe aggregate it if you can. By the way I made another example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fthctxfy/)

Comment: Better to replace `return isLast ? this.y : '';` with `return isLast ? this.y : null;` if you have a lot of data. Otherwise it won't get printed