# How to mark last point in spline chart Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to mark last point in spline chart. 
Here, data is fetched from API.

```
plotOptions: {
    spline: {
      marker: {
        symbol: 'triangle',
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }
```

Note: Need to find the last point and show the indicator on it.

Comment: This answer should get you what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36679677/2596103. It shows you how to use the data formatter function to find the last point and add the indicator.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is this question different as the previous one you asked? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206229/show-indicator-at-last-point-on-highchart-spline-chart)  Because there you are asking the same thing?